# How to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, radicals

I have seen this fact thrown around a lot and never really stopped to prove it; plugging in a few values convinced me of its truth. But I would like to see the result proved. To be clear, this is not homework, just human curiosity; I'm looking for any nice proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite as

$$
\sqrt[n]{n}=n^{1/n} = e^{\ln(n)/n}
$$
Now, you can write that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\ln(n)/n} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)/n}
$$
Looking at the exponent, you have (using L'Hopital's Rule)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n = 0
$$
Therefore, you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = e^0 = 1
$$

Comment: by far the simplest and most easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt[n]{n}=1+t$. Then $$n=(1+t)^n\geq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2\Rightarrow t^2\leq\frac{2}{n-1}\rightarrow0~(n\rightarrow\infty)$$So $\lim_{n\rightarrow0}t=0$, for otherwise $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t^2\neq0$, a contradiction.

Comment: how do you know $(1+t)^n > (n)(n-1)t/2$?

Comment: ah, I see, its from the binomial expansion...

Comment: Also, there's no no need for your contradiction. Simply take roots on both sides of your last inequality and you'll have that $t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Coffee_Table, yes, that will also work. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: no problem. this is a pretty neat proof.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that for a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive terms, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {\root n\of {a_n}}$ and the two limits are equal.

This is easy to apply here ...

See [these notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20130728110356/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series4.pdf) of [Pete L. Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) for a proof of the above stated fact.

Comment: As far sa I can tell, the notes linked in the post eventually became one part of  the text [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf). (Just in case, here is a [Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220503044808/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Observe that 
$$
\sqrt[n]{n} = n^{1/n} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\log(n)}.
$$
Since $e : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, taking the limit gives 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}\log(n)} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log(n)}.
$$
It can be shown in a variety of ways (Taylor expansion comes to mind) 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(n) = 0,
$$
and hence 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = e^0 = 1.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I posted the exact same solution seconds after Glen O.  Oops!